# STP recovery on tree root failure and recovery?

Tags: networking, switch, bridge, tree

What happens in an STP topology if the root node fails then recovers?

After the failure I guess that the two segments elect a new root for each one. When the old root returns, does it get back as root after a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should eventually return to the normal STP config.

Comment: Please define "normal". Any link to a reference?

Comment: normal == the way it was before...if you understand the root bridge election process, it should just return.  You might have to power cycle the new "root" to get an election to take place if your hardware doesn't support pre-empt.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/univercd/cc/td/doc/product/rtrmgmt/sw_ntman/cwsimain/cwsi2/cwsiug2/vlan2/stpapp.htm